# Django Rest Framework depth based on direction

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class OrgUser(User):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, related_name='users')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrgUser
        depth = 1
        fields = ('email', 'role', 'organization',)

class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    users = USerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        depth = 1
        fields = ('name', 'users',)
```

I'm using the Django REST Framework and I'm trying to get the following output for the given URLS:

`GET /organization/`

```
{
    'name':'Hello World',
    'users':[{ 'email':'test@gmail.com', 'role':'A' }]
}
```

`GET /user/`

```
{
    'email':'test@gmail.com',
    'role':'A',
    'organization':{ 'name':'Hello World' }
}
```

So what's happening is `GET /organization/` is giving me the users array and the organization information *again*.

I've been racking my brain setting the `depth` property on my serializer, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. If someone could please point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you want different output from your `UserSerializer` depending on if it's being used alone (i.e. at `GET /user/`) or as a nested relation (i.e. at `GET /organization/`).

Assuming you want different fields in both, you could just create a third `Serializer` to use for the nested relationship that only includes the fields you want in the `OrganizationSerializer`. This may not be the most elegant way to do it, but I can't find any alternatives.

Sample code:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class OrgUser(User):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, related_name='users')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrgUser
        depth = 1
        fields = ('email', 'role', 'organization',)

class OrganizationUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer): # New Serializer
    class Meta:
        model = OrgUser
        depth = 1
        fields = ('email', 'role',)

class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    users = OrganizationUserSerializer(many=True) # Change to new serializer
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        depth = 1
        fields = ('name', 'users',)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I knew there was a simple solution, I was just making it way more complex than it should be. Thanks again.